# J2me developing via android phone

Tags: java, android, ide, java-me, emulation

I want to develop applications for Nokia devices like Nokia c2-01 using my Android device. My question is if it possible, and if so, which work environment is recommended?

Thanks.

Comment: Android Studio, https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html, is the official development environment.  Earlier there was an Eclipse environment but that was replaced.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio

Comment: Android Studio is only for development of Android apps. He's asking for tools to develop JavaME on an Android device.

Answer (score 5):

There is **Java ME to Android bridge**, known as *J2AB*, which contains the Java ME API wrapper to translate into corresponding Android API. But the J2AB is quite limited and you can adjust and implement more Java ME API support into J2AB source codes easily. Link: https://app.assembla.com/spaces/j2ab/wiki/Converting_From_J2ME.

Other framework that creates Android App is **MicroEmu**. The difference with J2AB is it draws the Java ME UI components into the Android Canvas entirely, not translating to native Android UI components. For using this, you have to use the microemu-android package to build. Link: http://microemu.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/converting-javame-applications-to.html.

The basic to develop Java ME applications, the **Sun Java Wireless Toolkit** is generally used. You can download at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html. And use the **NetBeans** or **Eclipse** IDE with Java ME plugins loaded for easy Java ME development. Sorry, I don't know if the IDE for developing Java ME source codes exists for Android, only for Windows or Linux desktop computers.